# Android onBackPressed wont exit

Tags: android

I have problem with the `onBackPressed` method in my app.
The problem is when I press back it goes to the last activity instead of exiting.

This is my code:

```
Private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this,           
R.string.exit_press_back_message,                
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Are you trying to go back to the last activity or trying to finish the app?

Comment: Are you trying to kill your app and clean your all activities?

Comment: This is because of the android stack. I guess you have opened this activity from inside your last activity, then the last one is still alive. You have to call finish() at the last activity if you don´t want this...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you don´t want to go back to the last activity on back press, you have to call finish. Example, You are starting a new activity outside another one, then this activity stays alive if you don´t call finish. To get your expectation work, simply call finish like this in your activity where you start another one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

### EDIT

Is it not absolutely clear what exactly you are asking. From your comment now I guess your activity won´t finish. The problem is here:

```
  if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

You made a global boolean

```
Private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
```

but if you never change this value, your back press will never finish the activity. `if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce)`  means if this value is `true`....but it isn´t because you initialized it to false and if you does not make changes later for example `doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;` it stays false.

Comment: I changed my code and add finish after every intent and now in the main it's still wont exit after a double back click.. it's stay in the main..

Comment: That´s another problem, you need to reqork your question that it is understandable. I make an edit

Comment: are you sure that your posted code in the question is still actual? Maybe you have removed `doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;` ? Or you have opened your activity multiple times...

Answer (score 0):

- First of all finish any previous activity before you start the one that has the double tap to exit

Then your code will work

Answer (score 0):

super.onBackPressed() won't end the app. It will just end the current activity. 
You need to call this.finishAffinity() to close the application.